# Direct product decomposition of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ (Bott-Tu Exercise 6.5)

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, geometry

I want to show:

(a) there is a direct product decomposition of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ to the direct product of $O(n)$ and positive definite symmetric matrices;

(b) use (a) to deduce that the structure group of any real vector bundle may be deduced into $O(n)$.

For (a) I tried to use the Gram-Schmidt procedure, but I can only get $G=TO$ where $G\in GL(n,\mathbb{R})$, $O\in O(n)$, $T$ an upper trangle matrix, and I cannot find a way to produce positive definite symmetric matrices.

For (b) I just have no idea. I think I need the explicit isomorphism from (a).

Comment: **HINT**: Let $S$ be the positive square root of $A^\top A$. Consider $A=(AS^{-1})S$.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! I have worked out (a). However, I still don't know how to approach (b). I think I want to show there exists matrix $P$ such that $AS^{-1}=PAP^{-1}$ (i.e. they are similar). Is this true? @TedShifrin

Comment: No, deform the positive-definite symmetric factor to the identity.

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit more on how to "deform"? I have the cocycle functions $g_{\alpha\beta}:U_\alpha\cap U_\beta\to GL(n,R)$, and by (a) we know it may be written as  $g_{\alpha\beta}=g_{\alpha\beta}^1g_{\alpha\beta}^2$ where the first part is orthogonal and the second part is positive definite. I think I need to show $g_{\alpha\beta}^1$ is equivalent to $g_{\alpha\beta}$, i.e. they are similar. @TedShifrin

Comment: No, not similar, look carefully at the Lemma they refer to. But you can actually apply (a) not just to the 1-cocycles but to the trivializations on $U_\alpha$, can you not?

Comment: Thanks, I now realized my previous mistake. Also, I realized that I should not use $g_{\alpha\beta}$ to find $\lambda_\alpha$, since that would make my $\lambda_\alpha$ rely on $\beta$, therefore I should indeed find $\lambda_\alpha$s from $\phi_\alpha:E|_{U_\alpha}\to U_\alpha\times\mathbb{R}^n$. But how could I apply (a) to $\phi_\alpha$s? (it is not a $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$-valued function)? I have spent a lot of time trying to make $\lambda_\alpha$ ''naturally'' arise from $\phi_\alpha$, but there's just no matrix to work with :( @TedShifrin